# Big Query - ANY_VALUE returning Null

Tags: google-bigquery, aggregate-functions

I am trying to use "any_value" function in BQ but it keeps me returning NULL.

Below is the case example of my problem.
Important to note that it is working fot **tid** field but not for **seller** (the one I really need)

I have no idea why it is happening.

```
select 
  *
  , any_value(seller) over (partition by gid) as other_seller
  , any_value(tid) over (partition by gid) as other_tid

FROM `my_Table`
```

[image: Query result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have no idea why it is happening.

ANY_VALUE behaves as if RESPECT NULLS is specified; rows for which expression is NULL are considered and may be selected.

Consider below option then

```
select 
  *
  , max(seller) over (partition by gid) as other_seller
  , max(tid) over (partition by gid) as other_tid

FROM `my_Table`
```

In case if you want to randomize output  - try below

```
select 
  *
  , first_value(seller) over (partition by gid order by if(seller is null, 1, rand())) as other_seller
  , first_value(tid) over (partition by gid order by if(tid is null, 1, rand())) as other_tid

FROM `my_Table`
```

Comment: But how/why does it work for the other column ? I thought that nulls values were ignored by the function

Comment: it is what it is! it (ANY_VALUE function) is not deterministic nor random. and output logic is not guaranteed to follow any logic unless you tweak as in my answer!